# Configuring UPS with NUT (on 16.04 LTS): UPS responding but computer not resuming after shutdown

Tags: power-management, configuration, ups, nut

I am attempting to install a UPS onto my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server. Besides the power connection the UPS has a USB cable connection to the PC.

I am using nut ([network ups tools](http://networkupstools.org)), which I installed with

```
sudo apt install nut nut-monitor usbhid-ups
```

I then edited the configuration files in /etc/nut , adapting the instructions found at http://networkupstools.org/docs/user-manual.chunked/ar01s06.html (which used slightly different paths).

I successfully got to the stage in the instructions where /var/log/syslog contained messages such as

```
May 29 01:11:27 mybox upsmon[102]: Startup successful
May 29 01:11:28 mybox upsd[100]: Client monuser@192.168.50.1
logged into UPS [myupsname]
```

When I got to the "testing shutdown" section I had my first serious problem: to test a forced shutdown sequence I was told to issue the command

```
upsmon -c fsd
```

...with the expectation that "If everything works correctly, the computer will be forcibly powered off, may remain off for a few seconds to a few minutes (depending on the driver and UPS type), then will power on again."

What happened was that the computer did shut down and then never came back on. Note I have explicitly configured the BIOS to turn the computer "always on" when power is reapplied after a power cut (as opposed to "last state" or "always off").

How do I diagnose why it's not coming back on, and what can I do to remedy?